# The declared package "com.example.android.softkeyboard" does not match the expected package "your.test.com.example.android.softkeyboard"

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

Im recieving  the title error on several lines I used a example to create a application I did create a folder for .com.example.. and placed it in the root directory but it did not work I tried editing the Java script manually and it also did not work..

Comment: Did you create a class with SoftKeyboard in your package?

Comment: What does the very first line in your java file say? Something like `package ...`

Comment: what do mean? like <Softkeyboard... I am extremely new to app development I do not have a softkeyboard folder in my root..do I have to declare the class in Java if so where..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, it sounds like the top of your class with the compile error you mentioned has a package declaration like the following:

`package com.example.android.softkeyboard;`

However, the package that actually contains the class is as follows:

`your.test.com.example.android.softkeyboard`

You need to either change the package declaration line to look like the package directory structure or change the name of the package to look like the package declaration in the code. The latter option would be better because I suspect you've probably copied code from somewhere into your own package and that's why things aren't compiling.  If you start renaming packages, you may cause more compile errors to appear before getting everything fixed.  If you're new to Java, this can be very confusing to deal with.

If you are completely unfamiliar with how packages work, or if you'd like to read up on it, here are some good resources:

[Oracle Java Package Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)
[Wikipedia Java Package Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package)

Comment: I did what you said!! IT worked!! BUT.....now Java says it cant read my softkeyboard xml file?? thnx for the resources!!

Comment: Great!  Please upvote and accept ;)  As far as the XML file goes... that's going to depend on a number of things - how is java attempting to read the xml file (String filepath or URL), is it using a relative file path, etc.

Comment: ok I dont have enough reps to upvote I have no idea how to get them and thanks again